# How to display the minutes and seconds inputs ONLY in NgbTimepicker

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Currently the *NgbTimepicker* directive has a configuration option (*seconds*) to display or not the seconds input box. I'd like to do away with the hour input box instead, displaying the minutes and seconds input boxes alone for a particular project.

I cannot figure out a way to do this without hacking the core code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

The way I have done it so far is with css

```
:host ::ng-deep .ngb-tp-hour * {
  display: none;
  visibility: none;
}

/* Below worked for the spacer placeholder : */

:host ::ng-deep .ngb-tp-spacer:nth-child(2) {
  display: none;
  visibility: none;
}
```

I am actually interested if there is another way because if the CSS class names changed...

Answer (score 2):

Use this css style to remove the hour from the DOM

```
.ngb-tp-hour[_ngcontent-c0] {
    display: none;
}
```

I am working on to remove the `:` will update once I complete

Comment: Thanks. I had tried CSS (which worked as noted in my edit). Was wondering if that was the best way.

Comment: the properties are not exposed. so you have to go with this

Comment: Any particular reason for the [_ngcontent-c0] added to the class?

Comment: Nope :( try without that

Comment: did you find a solution to remove the colon

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the classic js code inside the timepicker component.ts file

```
 ngOnInit() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('ngb-tp-hour')[0].remove();
    document.getElementsByClassName('ngb-tp-spacer')[0].remove();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use to hide hours and the first colon ( : )

`.ngb-tp-hour,.ngb-tp div:nth-child(2){
     display: none !important;
}`